# How to integrate hadoop and storm?

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

I recently came across project Storm for real time analytics. I was wondering how Hadoop and Storm can be integrated for processing data.Also,I need suggestions for various projects that use the combination of both.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

So Storm has the concept of Bolt & Spout.

Bolt does processing while spouts get data into the system.

Storm provides a Storm-Hdfs Connector through which you can write data to the disk directly through a Bolt.

Comment: So, using this connector we actually store real time data into Hdfs? and is this data is available for processing using mappers and reducers.Anyways thanks for your help,also i'll look into it and i'll share if i come across anything.

Comment: Can you please give me  some resources about this connector, that I can refer?

Comment: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_user-guide/content/ch_storm-using-hdfs-connector.html